# how get value of aspxcombobox in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have `aspxcombobox`(**Devexpress**)
asp.net :

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <dx:ListBoxColumn FieldName="cg_id" />
                <dx:ListBoxColumn FieldName="cg_name" />
            </Columns>
            </dx:ASPxComboBox>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categorys_Group]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Accounting/Check.aspx?id=" + ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem.GetValue("cg_name"));
        }
```

When click button. i want to get value index selected of `aspxcombobox`.
I try get value of **combobox**, but it only return value first ( = 0 ).

WHo can help me? get value of `aspxcombobox`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by wrong `selectedItem` or `selectedIndex` property or when `aspxcombobox` is empty etc.

```
MessageBox.show(ASPxComboBox1.Value != null? ASPxComboBox1.Value.ToString():string.Empty);
```

To skip from this error you should know [ValueType](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_ValueTypetopic) property properly.
And also see it..

- [ASPxClientComboBox_GetSelectedItem](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientComboBox_GetSelectedItemtopic)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1. on the code behind, create a switch case on the index selected, and bindes the data to comboBox accordingly.
2. on the data level: in your data base access layer, using your Data Provider class that fetches data from your database, you have to create a **GET** method that takes the **SELECTED INDEX** as a parameter, pass that **SELECTED INDEX** to a pre-defined **STORED PROCEDURE** and do a SELECT according to the choosen index.

I would suggest using the second solution for the following reasons:

1. no changes made on the code behind side.
2. fetch is done on the database level according to the selected index, which assures the correct data imported. --> Your Data Source is Bound earlier in the process.
3. small changes are made on the STORED PROCEDURE :)

Best Regards,
ANDOURA